# Bringing user control to front by clicking on one user control

Tags: c#, winforms, button, user-controls

I need some Help here.
I have 4-5 user controls stacked upon one another.All are of same size and only the one on top is visible.
I have a button on the top most user control.
I wish that when I click the button that usercontrol is sent to back and another user control is brought to front.
This is my Code:

```
 private void btnaddcstmrdashbrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addorder addorder = new addorder();
        this.Visible = false;
        this.SendToBack();
        addorder.Visible = true;
        addorder.BringToFront();
    }
```

What happens is, The top most userControl is no more visible.
However the other user Control does not com to front and is not visible.
I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: This: `addorder addorder = new addorder();` is of course a new instance of a Control, unrelated to the existing. Just `SendToBack()` your current Control. If you want to `BringToFront()` a specific Control, you need its current instance. If you are trying to create a multi-panel Menu style layout, use a TabControl without headers.

Comment: Are the "4-5" instances all of the SAME TYPE of UserControl?...or are they all different, custom types of UserControls.  How do you know which other UserControl should be brought to the front based on the current "top" one?

Comment: @Jimi how Should I find its current instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>If the user controls are in different types, you can refer to the following code. Bind the same method to the button that in user control, and use switch to judge the user control type.</strike>

```
UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
UserControl2 userControl2 = new UserControl2();
UserControl3 userControl3 = new UserControl3();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button1 = new Button
    {
        Text = "Next Control",
        Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
    };
    button1.Click += Button_Click;

    Button button2 = new Button
    {
        Text = "Next Control",
        Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
    };
    button2.Click += Button_Click; 
        
    Button button3 = new Button
    {
        Text = "Next Control",
        Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
    };
    button3.Click += Button_Click;

    userControl1.Controls.Add(button1);
    userControl2.Controls.Add(button2);
    userControl3.Controls.Add(button3);

    Controls.Add(userControl1);
    Controls.Add(userControl2);
    Controls.Add(userControl3);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string controlName = ((Button)sender).Parent.Name;

    switch (controlName)
    {
        case "UserControl1":
            userControl2.BringToFront();
            break;
        case "UserControl2":
            userControl3.BringToFront();
            break;
        case "UserControl3":
            userControl1.BringToFront();
            break;
    }
}
```

The test result,

[image]

---

**Update**

If the button is added from designer, you can refer to the following code.

First, define the usercontrol property in Form1.cs. And pass the Form object via parameter.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 form1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = this;
    }

    public UserControl1 UC1{get;set;}
    public UserControl2 UC2{get;set;}
    public UserControl3 UC3{get;set;}

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC1 = new UserControl1(form1);
        UC2 = new UserControl2(form1);
        UC3 = new UserControl3(form1);
        Controls.Add(UC1);
        Controls.Add(UC2);
        Controls.Add(UC3);
    }
}
```

Then, modity the code in UserControl1.cs.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public Form1 f1;

    public UserControl1(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f1 = form1;
    }

    // this button is dragged and dropped from toolbox
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.UC2.BringToFront();
        //f1.UC3.BringToFront();
        //f1.UC1.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Do the same for the rest of UserControls.

Comment: The Button itself is in one of the user control

Comment: Do you mean that you have added the button in UserControl Dedigner? If so, please refer to the update content.

Comment: No /i haven't added the button in the designer. I dragged and dropped the the button inside a user control

Comment: @ShreeramGharote Drag and drop? This is what I mean that add button in designer. I also do this operation in my test, drag and drop the button into each usercontrol.

Comment: Ok,But I dont get why you put in the code button button1 = new button;

Comment: @ShreeramGharote Please refer to the update part in the answer, it didn't add any button by coding.

Comment: Thankyou very much